# How to reproduce successful openssl_verify

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption

My web app has an endpoint that receives a POST from a webhook, and the service that sends the payload also signs it using `openssl_sign`.

As you'd expect, I know the service's public key, so I use `openssl_verify` and check whether the "signature" sent to my endpoint matches the "payload" ("payload" and "signature" are the parameter names).

It all works fine.

What I want to do now is write a functional test of my endpoint's controller. I want to prove that it properly handles when "payload" and "signature" are verified vs when "payload" and "signature" are invalid.

Since I do NOT have the service's private key, I can't generate my own values for the test case.

So I've used logging to see real-world values of "payload" and "signature".

But then when I use those values for my test, it fails!

I think the problem has something to do with line-break characters or whatever might not be captured 100% accurately by Laravel logging.

How can I capture EXACTLY what the production "payload" and "signature" are?

P.S. I also did this:

```
$payload = $request->input(self::PARAM_PAYLOAD);
Log::debug(sha1($payload));
Log::debug($payload);
```

And then when I look in the log for the `$payload` value and run `sha1` on it, the hash is not the same as the logged hash of the original `$payload`.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` didn't help and `serialize` didn't help. What finally worked was:

```
$payload = $request->input(self::PARAM_PAYLOAD);
Log::debug(encrypt($payload));
```

Whether the corruption was happening because of linebreaks, single quotes, double quotes, or other special characters, apparently the `encrypt` function made it a non-issue.

So then I copied the encrypted payload value out of my log and pasted it into a `const` in my test.

And then I decrypted the payload prior to running the test. Pass!

I still don't understand the root cause of the problem, but at least this workaround helped.